# Android Custom Listview with Filter not working

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom listview and want to filter records with it. Please help. I want to filter stident records by name.

I tried multiple options available over internet but none is working.

My mainactivity(Student activity here) code :

```
String[] arr_uid = new String[50];
String[] arr_name = new String[50];
String[] arr_mobile = new String[50];
// these arrays are populated form database then

 Student_custom_Adapter adapter = new Student_custom_Adapter(StudentActivity.this, arr_uid, arr_name, arr_mobile);

                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_student);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

my custom adapter class :

```
public class Customer_custom_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] uid1;
    private final String[] mobile;
    private final String[] name;
    

    public Student_custom_Adapter(Activity context, String[] uid, String[] name , String[] mobile, ) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_students, uid);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.uid1= uid;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.name= name;
       

    }


    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        String finaldate;
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_student, null,true);


        
        TextView tv_uid = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cust_uid);
        TextView tv_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cust_name);
         TextView tv_mobile = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cust_mobile) ;
        
       
           tv_uid.setText("ID: "+ uid[position]);
            tv_name.setText("Name: "+name[position]);
            tv_mobile.setText("Mobile : "+mobile[position]);
           
        }

        return rowView;



    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int j = 0 ;

int temp =0;


for (String s : arr_name) {

    if (s != null && s.contains(name)) {

        filter_uid[j] = arr_uid[temp];

        filter_name[j] = arr_name[temp];

        filter_name[j] = arr_mobile[temp];

        ++j;
    }
```

temp++;

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter it yourself and then update the array in your adapter with the filtered array. Something like the following:

**StudentActivity.java**:

```
...

String[] arr_uid = new String[50];
String[] arr_name = new String[50];
String[] arr_mobile = new String[50];

...

private void filterList(String name) {
    String[] filter_uid = new String[50];
    String[] filter_name = new String[50];
    String[] filter_mobile = new String[50];
    int j = 0;
    for (String s : arr_name) {
        if (s != null && s.contains(name)) {
            filter_uid[j] = arr_uid[j];
            filter_name[j] = s;
            filter_name[j] = arr_mobile[j];
            ++j;
        }
    }
    adapter.updateList(filter_uid, filter_name, filter_mobile);
}
```

**Customer_custom_Adapter.java**

```
/* Do not declare as final */
private String[] uid1;
private String[] mobile;
private String[] name;

...

/* Add this method; call it to update your list */
public void updateList(String[] uid, String[] name, String[] mobile) {
    this.uid1= uid;
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this.name= name;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: It should work. Did you write the remaining part your Customer_custom_Adapter properly? Did you populate your arrays properly? Finally, you have to call filterString(someName) after populating your adapter.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I at first used counter as i then replaced with j but slipped that two places. Now I have corrected it.

Comment: Thank You Ananta for your prompt help. Good this is above code is not crashing but unfortunately when I type any value to search , system changes value of name in all records to "NULL"

Comment: I got the issue. I had to tweak your code a little. Actually the above code is iterating through arr_name , arr_uid and arr_mobile. In the above code we are only incrementing the variable J when the condition is true . However , we need to continue the loop across arr_name.arr_uid and arr_mobile. So here is the updated code :